# Forget the vertical alignment of some text / a figure /

Tags: vertical-alignment, includegraphics, vertical

Any piece of text in LaTeX (be it a figure, an inline equation, or really just text) has an inherent preference of how it is to be aligned vertically. E.g. text wants to be aligned as it should be, figures (imported by `\includegraphics`) by default want to be aligned according to their bottom, etc.

How can I forget the vertical alignment of any piece of LaTeX code?